# How to update if field exist for a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert, database-trigger

I have a problem with my requests, I have to update my existing field and not make an insert because it will be duplicated and I already know the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE or REPLACE but it doesn't work the goal would be to update the quantity of my product and not to insert some. I tried via triggers but it doesn't work either, do you have the solution to my problem?

```
INSERT INTO cart(product_id, quantity) VALUES (4, quantity +1 )
```

But if the product is already existing it adds a line to me and I would like it to automatically detect it to update it, knowing that my field is not a key

```
UPDATE cart SET quantity = quantity+1 WHERE id= id
```

And this is my trigger :

```
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT product_id FROM cart WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id)
THEN
    UPDATE cart SET quantity = NEW.quantity WHERE id = NEW.user_id;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO cart(product_id, quantity) VALUES (NEW.product_id, NEW.quantity);        
END IF;
```

END

This is a problem :
Two rows as identic and i would like for this exemple one row like at line with id 1

[Image expalin problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Xwr.png)

Thank a lot and sorry for my englsih and expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a trigger. You can use [MySQL `insert ... on duplicate key` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

```
insert into cart(product_id, quantity) 
    values (4, 1)
    on duplicate key update quantity = quantity + values(quantity)
```

For this to work, you need a unique constraint (or a primary key constraint) on column `product_id`.

With this syntax, if a record already exists with the same `product_id` that the one that you are trying to insert, an `update` is executed instead, that adds the new `quantity` to the existing record.

Comment: But if I have a new user and I make to unique; a user id 2 for exemple don't have a product number 4 :/ because it's unique , is situation is : user_id  = 1, product id = 4, quantity = 2 and user_id = 2, product_id = 4 and quantity = 5 for exeple this it's impossible

Comment: @Amelya: there is no `user_id` involved in your example. Does this column belong to `cart`?

Comment: in [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Xwr.png) have exemple of registry of my cart

Comment: OK so you probably you want a unique constraint on `(user_id, product_id)`. Column `user_id` should be part of your `insert` statement too, so: `insert into cart(user_id, product_id, quantity) 
    values (1, 4, 1)
    on duplicate key update quantity = quantity + values(quantity)`

Comment: For the moment id is a primary key and is alone, no contraint of user_id and product_id, idea of this system : a user can order several articles, but an article must be present only on one line in relation to the user so for example: user 1 product 4 quantity 2 and user 2 product 4 quantity 5, contraint of one product each user and increment value of quantity, actualy only id as primary key and index for product_id and user_id

Comment: @Amelya: yes. So your explanation confirms that you need a unique constraint on `(user_id, product_id)`. You can create it like so: `ALTER TABLE cart ADD UNIQUE cart_constraint(user_id, product_id);`

Comment: thank but now i have this : sqlMessage: "Erreur de syntaxe près de '+1)' à la ligne 1" (translate : syntax error near '+1' at row 1),
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: `INSERT INTO cart(user_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES (1,4, quantity +1 ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + VALUES(quantity+1)` Key are now unique

Comment: You should assign a quantity of `1` (or some other number), not `quantity + 1`. So: `INSERT INTO cart(user_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES (1, 4, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + VALUES(quantity)`

Comment: if user click a first time on button mysql insert quantity 1 but if click again mysql update quantity 2, 3 etc.. that's why I chose to do +1 in  SQL directly

Comment: @Amelya: the query I gave you does exactly that. Please test it.

Comment: thank its work aproximatibely but its work for the moment ;)